# CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY when object is smaller than CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, opencl

Querying the specific device that I am using, I find that `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE = 0.4 GB`.  From my understanding, this value is the maximum buffer size that can be created.  However, when I perform

```
clCreateBuffer(context,
        CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
        sizeof(Object)*n,
        &obj,
        &error);
```

where `sizeof(Object)*n ~= 0.2 GB`, I get a `CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY` error.  I'm guessing that I have a misunderstanding of these two params, and was hoping that I could get some clarification.

Comment: Memory fragmentation? Can't allocate a buffer of size X if there are no contiguous memory runs of at least X.

Comment: Plausible -- in that case `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` would be a theoretical cap?

Comment: Update: `CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY` is thrown when the size is 1 KB, so I'm guessing that this isn't a lack of memory issue, but rather some invocation problem on my part.

Comment: You've almost certainly killed my conjecture dead with that one.

Comment: What platform and device are you using? What operating system? How much RAM does your computer have?